# How to solve blank page while running second vue app under nginx?

Tags: macos, vue.js, nginx, nginx-config

Need to run multiple Vue.js v3 apps with ngnix under macOS Big Sur.

First app located in: /Users/kharraz/Developer/code/homeapp/dist;

Second app: /Users/kharraz/Developer/code/businessapp/dist;
The two folders contains yarn build output;

The goal is when i tape localhost or localhost/homeapp takes me to the first app and when i type localhost/businessapp takes me to the second app.

With my current conf, localhost/homeapp/index.html is working but the second localhost/businessapp/index.html is giving me a blank page.

Both apps are working fine under localhost:8001 and localhost:8002.
Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-Host $host;
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            break;
        }

        location /markets {
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen 8001;
        
        location / {
            root /Users/kharraz/Developer/code/homeapp/dist;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name businessapp;
        listen 8002;

        location / {
            root /Users/kharraz/Developer/code/businessapp/dist;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the behavior change if you comment out the `break` directive?

Comment: No, it stills the same

Answer (score 0):

Manually make the App route to path '/' instead of depending on Vue to take to homepage.

```
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRouter();

    const doOpeningCeremony = async () => {
      route.push({path: '/'});
    }

    onMounted(doOpeningCeremony);
  },
}
```